# Question about proving the remainder and factor theorem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Ok so remainder theorem states that if we have polynomial P(x) then it can be written out in following form :
$$P(x)=g(x)f(x) + r(x)$$

Then if f(x)=x-a and r(x) = r we have : $$P(x) = g(x)(x-a) + r$$

As next step they take x=a and end up with fact that P(x)=r

Now my question is,how does substituting x by a prove anything ?

Same goes for factor theorem

Answer (score 2):

What they are proving is that $P(a)=r$.  This is a statement about one particular value of the polynomial.  This is one way to find $r$.  It is not true that $P(x)=r$

Comment: Oh,well thanks,topic closed